# shorter way for jquery show/hide functions

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am learning JQuery and understand what I coded below as it works perfect. To me it is simple but it seems like it is somewhat messy. Is there a simpler way to accomplish the same result in shorthand or combine the functions. That is showing and hiding different DIVs when clicking images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#leftcolumn').hide();
    $('#2d').hide();
    $('#development').hide();
    $("#HideFlash").click(function () {
        $('#movie').toggle("slow");
        $('#leftcolumn').toggle('slow');
            return false;

        })
    });

    $('#leftcolumn').toggle('slow');


    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".img1").click(function () {
        $('#2d').toggle("slow");
            return false;

    })
});

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".img2").click(function () {
        $('#development').toggle("slow");
            return false;

    })
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">


<div id="body" align="center">
<a id="HideFlash" href="#">hide video</a>
<div id="movie">

flash object movie here

</div>  
</div>


<div id="leftcolumn"> 
    <h1>Stephen Carl Willis:<br> 
    Web Developer/Designer</h1> 
    <ul>
    <li><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/close.png" alt="2d" class="img1">2D</></li>
    <li><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/images/close.png" alt="2d" class="img2">Development</></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


<div id="2d">
Here is my 2D graphic design. This includes vector, flash, ect.
</div>
<div id="development">
Here is my development portfolio.
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove the second and third `$(document).ready( ... );` wrapper, as this code is running within an event handler already. If you post some HTML / css, maybe in a jsfiddle, people will be able to help out

Comment: Thanks Dom for the advice.

Comment: `$('#leftcolumn,#2d,#development').hide();` also cache your selectors. Also codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

people use tools like jsfiddle.net to post examples of problems or soutions. Here's what yours looks like when tidied up in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rJ8XR/

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#leftcolumn').hide();
    $('#2d').hide();
    $('#development').hide();
    $("#HideFlash").click(function () {
        $('#movie').toggle("slow");
        $('#leftcolumn').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    })
    $('#leftcolumn').toggle('slow');

    $(".img1").click(function () {
        $('#2d').toggle("slow");
        return false;

    })
    $(".img2").click(function () {
        $('#development').toggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

... removed extra `$(document).ready()` handlers, and cleaned up some html